# Gerrit + Jenkins

Tags: testing, jenkins, build, gerrit

I use jenkins + gerrit.

If I commit and push some changes and build-NOT-OK, I will see and fix it. When I fixed it, then commit and push, I see "Submitted, Merge Pending".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pending merge means one of two things.

1) There are two submits, and you are attempting to merge them in the wrong order.  If so, the latter merge will wait till the former merge is requested.

2) You have rejected the former merge, and the latter is waiting until you un-reject it and merge.  Since you probably won't do this, effectively this commit will never be merged.

some ways of fixing this

1) If you have a merge that should be rejected, resubmit it with the appropriate fixes.  This means that you `--amend` your prior commit and push it again.  Doing so will cause gerrit to "redo" the commit as it has the same Change-Id.

2) Capture the commit, and resubmit it on a clean pull.  This assures that the next time you push the new commit, it will be directly attached to the current head of your intended branch.  As there is nothing to wait on, the merge will go smoothly.

Other solutions exist; however, they get a bit more complicated (even if conceptually they are not hackish workarounds).  I find it is easier to gain a bit more experience thinking about merging and the history chain before exploring them.

Answer (score 0):

Merge pending normally means that the parent of the change is not submitted.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But if some changes abandoned because build-NOT-Ok, I fix code and push again. And I see the message in WebUI "Submitted, Merge Pending". But, if I enter in commit from WebUI, this commit have not Merge Conflicts.